# OVH domain name, changing the DNS server to godaddy hosting not working

Tags: hosting, nameservers, ovh

I have a hosting at godaddy, where I store some small websites.

I also purchased few domains at OVH. When I tried to change the DNS from original OVH to GoDaddy's, it was supposed to take up to 48 hours, but it's been three days now and the alert says 'Inactive; Updating', and when clicking on the details, the message says:

"Your domain does have DNS servers but they are not responding:

nsxx.domaincontrol.com
nsxx.domaincontrol.com"

(those are godaddy servers).

When checking with zonemaster website, I'm getting these errors:

"Nameserver nsxx.domaincontrol.com/2603:5:21b1::12 did not return NS records. RCODE was REFUSED."

Any idea what could be the problem?

Just a a side note, I have also another domain bought from OVH hosted on GoDaddy, and with the very same settings it works perfectly, so I'm a little lost. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? It's been 24 hours since I updated the IP address of my A records in OVH's DNS zone The records look ok now but all attempts to resolve return the old IPs. https://intodns.com is interesting.

Comment: Yes I have. What I did wrong is I changed the DNS, and then I tried to change IP, so as a result, I was changing the IP on the wrong DNS.

Solution was to reset the DNS to original OVH ones and then change the IP. See if this works

Comment: Sometime between 24 and 48 hours after updating my A records DNS resolved to the new IP.

Comment: Glad to hear that mate!